# HTML and PHP: Input form does not work properly on pressing "Enter" on IE 8

Tags: php, html, input, submit, enter

Here is a simple form with an input line and an input button:

```
<form name="input_form" action="process_data.php" method="post" >
    <input type="text" name="input" size="100"></input>
    <input type="submit" name="input_button" style="height: 25px;" />
</form>
```

If I press "Enter", everthing works fine under google chrome, IE 9 etc.

However, under IE 8 I need to press the submit button. It reacts also on "Enter", but not as it should. Presumably it does not fill the $_GET variable with the entered text.

How must the code modified (as simple as possible) such that it works properly on all browsers?

ED: I ask:

```
isset($_POST['input_button'])
```

But it is not set when pressing ENTER under IE 8.

Answer (score 1):

If a `submit` input doesn't have a value, it won't be posted. Try this:

```
<form name="input_form" action="process_data.php" method="post" >
    <input type="text" name="input" size="100" />
    <input type="submit" name="input_button" value="Submit!" style="height: 25px;" />
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, no positive effect. Can't one ask "is pressed button or pressed enter" in PHP (without using javascript). Otherwise I am going to reconstruct somewhat my code to avoid this problem.

Comment: No. PHP doesn't interface with the client. Ever. It only takes data and processes it on the server-side. May I ask why you need this value? Why not just use a `hidden` input?

Comment: Yes. How make it with a hidden button? Principally I would also like to have the submit button.

Comment: Just add a `hidden` input while keeping the submit button.'

Comment: I modfied isset($_POST['input_button']) to isset($_POST['input']). So I ask if the input text itself is set. For the moment it seems to work. Although it need not be a clean solution and might create other problems in future. It is a tinker solution.